# Laravel 5.1: Flatten Multidimensional array without removing keys

Tags: arrays, laravel-5.1, flatten

I'm trying to find a way to flatten a multidimensional array that doesn't remove the ID that is saved as a key.

I used this in my controller:

```
$dataslots = Dataslot::all()->map(function($dataslot) { return [$dataslot->id => $dataslot->maand->format('d-m-Y')]; });
```

The output of this is a multidimensional array that looks like:

```
Collection {#242 ▼
#items: array:4 [▼
0 => array:1 [▼
  1 => "01-12-2015"
 ]
1 => array:1 [▼
  2 => "01-01-2016"
 ]
2 => array:1 [▼
  3 => "01-02-2016"
 ]
3 => array:1 [▼
  4 => "01-03-2016"
 ]
]
}
```

I tried to use the Laravel Helper Function 'Array Flatten'. This method gives me the following result:

```
array:4 [▼
0 => "01-12-2015"
1 => "01-01-2016"
2 => "01-02-2016"
3 => "01-03-2016"
]
```

As you can see, the ID's which served as keys for my dates have been removed.

The result that I am looking for:

```
Collection {#243 ▼
#items: array:4 [▼
1 => "01-12-2015"
2 => "01-01-2016"
3 => "01-02-2016"
4 => "01-03-2016"
]
}
```

Comment: you can do: foreach ($objects as $o) { 
$flatArray[$o->id] = $o->date;
}

Comment: Not really sure how I need to change your code to suit mine. I tried this:
        foreach ($dataslots as $o) {
        $flatArray[$o->id] = $o->maand; 
        }

It returns the following error: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: you need to give us more info, about how you get your data? show us what you have right now

Comment: foreach ($dataslots as $o) {        $flatArray[$o['id']] = $o['maand'];         }